# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The prefix ns3 is not bound

Tags: jboss-eap-6

```
15:33:14,220 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."platform.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."platform.war".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "platform.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [jboss-as-server-7.4.3.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.4.3.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_241]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_241]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_241]
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The prefix ns3 is not bound.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:371)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:66)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:251)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:539)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.configuration.NonSpringBusHolder.configure(NonSpringBusHolder.java:118)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.aspect.BusDeploymentAspect.startDeploymentBus(BusDeploymentAspect.java:136)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.aspect.BusDeploymentAspect.start(BusDeploymentAspect.java:68)
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.deployers.AspectDeploymentProcessor.deploy(AspectDeploymentProcessor.java:74)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [jboss-as-server-7.4.3.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.4.3.Final-redhat-2]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The prefix ns3 is not bound.
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.getRefQName(SchemaBuilder.java:823)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.getRefQName(SchemaBuilder.java:831)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleElementGlobalType(SchemaBuilder.java:1308)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleElement(SchemaBuilder.java:404)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleSequence(SchemaBuilder.java:1546)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleComplexContentExtension(SchemaBuilder.java:1159)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleComplexContent(SchemaBuilder.java:1126)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleComplexType(SchemaBuilder.java:320)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleElement(SchemaBuilder.java:420)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleSchemaElementChild(SchemaBuilder.java:1509)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleXmlSchemaElement(SchemaBuilder.java:659)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.build(SchemaBuilder.java:157)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.read(XmlSchemaCollection.java:497)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.read(XmlSchemaCollection.java:483)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.xmlschema.SchemaCollection.read(SchemaCollection.java:133)
    at org.apache.cxf.databinding.AbstractDataBinding.addSchemaDocument(AbstractDataBinding.java:193)
    at org.apache.cxf.databinding.AbstractDataBinding.addSchemaDocument(AbstractDataBinding.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:400)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.initializeDataBindings(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:490)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:704)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:550)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:265)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:215)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:159)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.getServer(EndpointImpl.java:456)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:334)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: Hi Chris. Could you provide some context as to your error? Also if you could wrap the stack in trace in ``` either side of the block it'll be much easier to read. Thanks!

Comment: This was caused by a file jaxB.properties file in the compiled web-inf folder preventing Jboss to start properly thanks i am sorted

Comment: Hi Chris. Could you post an answer as to how you sovled the problem? You can then mark this as the correct answer (by the tick button). I'm sure someone else in the future will have the same issue and will likely find your solution!

Comment: If you also added a little detail above the stack trace in your original Question that'll help others understand your issue to determine if they are having the same problem. Thank you!